# Streaming .264 file in Gstreamer 1.0

Tags: video, streaming, udp, gstreamer

I'm trying to stream a .264 file.

While the direct pipeline without udp streaming plays the video fine, when using udp sink and src, only one frame of video is seen.

Direct Pipeline

gst-launch-1.0  filesrc location=football35228830.264 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! rtph264depay !  avdec_h264  ! autovideosink

This plays video fine.

Now when running these, the frozen video frame appears.

At Tx

gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location = football35228830.264 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=9001

At Client

gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=42050 !  application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=H264,payload=96 !  rtph264depay  ! h264parse ! avdec_h264  ! autovideosink

Is there any issue with the pipelines, or any additional elements are required?

Answer (score 0):

:There could be a few things: The file is loaded and played too fast => use multifilesrc. Also I add caps to the sender. Lastly, in your example the ports are different.

Sender:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v multifilesrc location=public/media/video.h264 loop=true ! \
video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1,profile=constrained-baseline ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=10 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=9001
```

Receiver:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=9001 ! 'application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=H264,payload=16' ! \
rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```